# Trying for dependent dropdown

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to do depending drop down on yii2

I have two tables :`course_details[id,course_id,_course_name], intake_details[id, course_id, course_name, intake_no,.....]`

The second table i only specified a few columns that i want to use for depdrop.

And then, i also applied similar field in another form

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'course_name')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(CourseDetails::find()->orderBy('course_type')->all(), 'course_id', 'course_name'),[
'prompt'=>'-Choose a Category-',
'onchange'=>'
            $.post( "index.php?r=intake-details/lists&course_id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
              $( "select#intake_no" ).html( data );
            });'  ]);?>

<?=  $form->field($model, 'intake_no')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(IntakeDetails::find()->all(), 'course_id', 'intake_no'),['prompt'=>'Select Intake']) ?>
```

And then my controller for intake details is like this:

```
  public function actionLists($course_id)
{
    
    $countPosts = IntakeDetails::find()
    ->select('intake_no')
    ->where(['course_id' => $course_id])
    ->count();
    
    $posts = IntakeDetails::find()
    ->select('intake_no')
    ->where(['course_id' => $course_id])
    
    ->all();
    
    if($countPosts>0){
        foreach($posts as $post){
            
            echo "<option value='".$post->course_id."'>".$post->intake_no."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option>-</option>";
    }
    
}
```

Supposedly the second drop down supposed to get the specific value and display based on that value from the first drop down , but doesn't work. It just display all of the value and it doesn't display values that have the same id. Can any one suggest another way to fix it ?

P.S: course_id column is not int but it managed to get the value. I have seen it using inspect in browser.

Comment: Did you try to check in browser dev tools if the ajax request is executed and what is it's result? It looks like your selector in `$( "select#intake_no" )` might be wrong because the ActiveForm generates IDs as `modelclass-attribute`. Because of that the ajax request might run correctly but the select is not updated. Your selector should look like `select#modelclass-inteke_no`. Replace the _modelclass_ with your actual model classname.

Comment: (index.php?r=intake-details/lists&course_id ) the list is not found. How to create it?